# Why can my laptop connect yet not my iPad/iPod Touch/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch, wifi

I just moved into a place with free internet.

Using Wi-Fi, I can connect with my laptop but not my iPad or iPhone. I can access the router (Netgear WGR614v9), the router setup page, and see the admin portion of it.

The SSID is broadcasting (I can see it with my laptop) but it doesn't show up on the list. I tried manually typing in the SSID and joining but my iDevices were unable to connect.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There are several incompatible  WiFi standards such as 802.11a, 802.11b, 802.11g  and 802.11n. In some cases, manufacturers implemented draft standards before they were ratified and this led to incomptibilities.

Some iDevices do not support 802.11n - so it may be that your WiFi access point (probably part of your router) is configured to use a standard that is not supported by your iDevices. You can configure your WiFi access point (router) to use a standard that you know your iDevices support.

Also some devices are simply better at picking up signals - it depends on product design and aerial size. If your iDevice can get a signal nearer the Wifi access point, you'll know that this is the probable cause.

Apple have some [guidance](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3304) for iPad users experiencing WiFi problems.

Comment: I am using 802.11g

Answer (score 0):

As per Red's suggestion and the fact that you say you can see the router's admin page, you *could* try to change the broadcast an 802.11b signal which may provide better compatibility with the iphone/ipad devices you have.

Note that this would reduce the theoretical speed limit down to 54Mbits/s but virtually any internet services in the US (Cable/DSL) are well below this so you won't throttle internet performance.

Also what is the signal strength that the laptop shows?  Typically a laptop will have better signal acquisition than an iphone/ipad.